# Finding the value of $ a $ in this equation

Tags: calculus, limits

The question is this : $$\lim_{x \to 1 }\left\{ \frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1} \right\}^{\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{1}{4}$$
And we have to find the value(s) of $ a $ for which the above equation is true. $a$ should be a non-negative integer.
I tried to estimate the limit by using first principle but in vain. Is it possible to apply L'hopitals rule in this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

\begin{align*}\lim_{x \to 1 }\left\{ \frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1} \right\}^{\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}}} = \lim_{x \to 1 }\left\{ \frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1} \right\}^{1+\sqrt{x}}\end{align*}
    we have 
    \begin{align*}\lim_{x \to 1 }\left\{ \frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1} \right\}  = \pm \frac{1}{2} \end{align*}
    Also,
    \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 1 }\left\{ \frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1} \right\} &= \lim_{x \to 1 }\left\{ \frac{\sin(x-1)-a(x-1)}{(x-1)+\sin(x-1)} \right\} \\
&= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \left\{ \frac{\sin t-at}{t+\sin t} \right\} \\
&= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \left\{ \frac{\cos t - a}{1+\cos t} \right\} \\
&= \frac{1-a}{2}
 \end{align*}
    Thus $\dfrac{1-a}{2} = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ and $a = 0, 2$.

Comment: The official answer key for the JEE-2014 (India) exam which had this question says the answer is only 0. The question there was find the largest value of a, which should be 2 but for some reason 2 is invalidated.  Is there a problem that a = 2 would create in the original expression?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$\left\{ \frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1} \right\}^{\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}}} =\left\{ \frac{-a+\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1}}{1+\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1}} \right\}^{1+\sqrt{x}} $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the exponent can be simplified as follows
$$\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x}}=1+\sqrt{x},$$
so that converges to $2$ as $x$ goes to $1$.

Now using L'Hôpital Rule on the term inside gives
$$\frac{-a+\cos(x-1)}{1+\cos(x-1)}$$
so this converges to $\frac{1-a}{2}$.

The whole expression thus converges to $\left(\frac{1-a}{2}\right)^2$. comparing this to $1/4$ gives $a=0,2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ x\to 1 } \left\{ \frac { -ax+\sin(x-1)+a }{ x+\sin(x-1)-1 }  \right\} ^{ \frac { 1-x }{ 1-\sqrt { x }  }  }=\lim _{ x\to 1 } \left\{ \frac { -ax+\sin(x-1)+a }{ x+\sin(x-1)-1 }  \right\} ^{ 1+\sqrt { x }  }=\\ =\lim _{ x\to 1 } \left\{ \frac { -a+\cos { (x-1) }  }{ 1+\cos { \left( x-1 \right)  }  }  \right\} ^{ 1+\sqrt { x }  }={ \left( \frac { -a+1 }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }\\ { \left( \frac { -a+1 }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \\\color{red} {a=0;2}\\ \\ $$